# Solving definite integrals with (ax+b)^n

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following problem without the chain rule or other "method", only formulas:

$$
g(x)=\int _{3x}^{x^3}\left(t^3+1\right)^{10}dt
$$

I'm used this formula, which is very helpful:

$$
\int k(ax+b)^n dx = \frac{k(ax+b)^{(n+1)}}{a(n+1)} +C
$$

So I get this to calculate the limits:

$$
\frac{1}{11}{(x^3+1)}^{11}-\frac{1}{11}{(3x+1)}^{11}
$$

But here I'm having the issue, because it would be a very long process to calculate but I'm sure there is a shorter way. What can I do in this case? Is this the right path?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is infact wrong.  You didn't notice in the formula that the term inside the bracket is linear while the term inside the bracket of your question is cubic.  So the answer won't go that way. The most common way would be using binomial expansion (using binomial theorem)  and then integrate

Comment: Oh damn! Didn't notice it. I'll do it with the binomial expansion then thanks, but now I'm curious, what are the other less common ways?

Comment: Speaking of higher level methods, you could write it in terms of incomplete beta function using the substitution $t^3=-x$ I guess